# .each loop inside a link_to loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in ruby and am trying to do a .each loop inside a link_to loop in order to make every single itiration (with the album cover, title and artiste) clickable as a block. something like this...

albums/index

```
<%= link_to (@album) do %>
  <% @albums.each do |album| %>
    <img src="<%= album.cover %>">
    <%= album.title %>
    <%= album.artist %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

albums_controller

```
def show
  @album = Album.find(params[:id])
  @tracks = @album.tracks
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :albums
 root 'albums#index'
end
```

$ rake routes

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
    albums GET    /albums(.:format)          albums#index     
           POST   /albums(.:format)          albums#create    
 new_album GET    /albums/new(.:format)      albums#new       
edit_album GET    /albums/:id/edit(.:format) albums#edit      
     album GET    /albums/:id(.:format)      albums#show      
           PATCH  /albums/:id(.:format)      albums#update    
           PUT    /albums/:id(.:format)      albums#update    
           DELETE /albums/:id(.:format)      albums#destroy   
      root GET    /                          albums#index
```

Each itiration is clickable but don't get /albums/:id. Where is the problem? Is it the link_to syntax?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be (swapped 2 first lines):

```
<% @albums.each do |album| %>
  <%= link_to album do %>
    <img src="<%= album.cover %>">
    <%= album.title %>
    <%= album.artist %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

For each album, you create the link for it instead of "create the link for each album". It doesn't work that way. Since you are new to programming, don't worry you will get used to it.

Comment: It should be `link_to album`, because `()` in `link_to (album)` is redundant. It still works. However, I edited my answer according to this. thanks.

Comment: Do you need to remove the `@` from `@album` so that it's using the album from the block params?

Answer (score 0):

How can `<% @albums.each do |album| %>` be working?
`@albums` is undefined (in your controller show action, you has only defined have `@album` (singular) and `@tracks`)
Also, you've posted the code of your `show` action but I think you are trying to get working an `index` action. 
If you controller was some like this:

```
def index
  @albums = Album.all
end
```

Then, in your view, you should write:

```
<% @albums.each do |album| %>
  <%= link_to album do %>
    <%= image_tag album.cover %>
    <%= album.title %>
    <%= album.artist %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Take a look at:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to